# High accuracy on both training and validation set, but extremely poor classification report

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, computer-vision

I'm working on my new Computer Vision Neural Network. Recently I've tried to train it for the first time. I was quite satisfied with the training results (I had ~99% accuracy on training set and ~94% on validation set) but when I tried to predict labels for the Test Set I got terrible classification report:

```
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.02      0.01      0.02        71
           1       0.29      0.29      0.29       483
           2       0.19      0.17      0.18       273
           3       1.00      0.00      0.00         6
           4       0.24      0.25      0.25       401
           5       0.05      0.07      0.06        57
           6       0.00      0.00      0.00        14
           7       0.17      0.19      0.18       253
           8       0.00      0.00      0.00         8

    accuracy                           0.22      1566    
   macro avg       0.22      0.11      0.11      1566 
weighted avg       0.22      0.22      0.22      1566
```

I tried to generate classification report for my Training Set also. I thought that if I've used it to train the network and got very high accuracy, I need to get great results there. But I didn't:

```
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.03      0.03      0.03       504
           1       0.32      0.32      0.32      3377
           2       0.17      0.16      0.17      1911
           3       0.00      0.00      0.00        44
           4       0.26      0.26      0.26      2808
           5       0.05      0.06      0.06       397
           6       0.01      0.01      0.01        98
           7       0.17      0.19      0.18      1768
           8       0.00      0.00      0.00        56

    accuracy                           0.23     10963
   macro avg       0.11      0.11      0.11     10963
weighted avg       0.23      0.23      0.23     10963
```

Here's my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Dropout
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ModelCheckpoint
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
import numpy as np
from keras.optimizers import Adam

# Defining paths to folders with train, test, and validation data
train_data = 'Train'
validation_data = 'Validation'
test_data = 'Test'

# Setting image width and height
img_width, img_height = 224, 224

# Creating ImageDataGenerator for training data with data augmentation
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator()
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=32,
    class_mode='categorical',
    shuffle=True
)
# Creating ImageDataGenerator for validation data
validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator()
validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    validation_data,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=32,
    class_mode='categorical',
    shuffle=True
)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator()
test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    test_data,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=32,
    class_mode='categorical',
    shuffle=False
)

# Creating a Sequential model
model = Sequential()

# Using a pretrained ResNet50 model with weights from 'imagenet'
pretrained_model = tf.keras.applications.resnet.ResNet50(
                    include_top=False,
                    weights='imagenet',
                    input_shape=(img_width, img_height, 3),
                    pooling='avg',
                    classes=9
                    )

#Freezing the layers of the pretrained model so they won't be trained
for layer in pretrained_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

# Adding the pretrained ResNet50 model to our sequential model
model.add(pretrained_model)

# Flattening the output of the pretrained model
model.add(Flatten())

# Adding a dense layer with 1024 units and ReLU activation
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))

# Adding the output layer with 9 units (one for each class) and softmax activation
model.add(Dense(9, activation='softmax'))

custom_adam = Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
# Compiling the model with the Adam optimizer and categorical_crossentropy loss
model.compile(optimizer=custom_adam, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Setting up callbacks for early stopping and model checkpointing
early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_accuracy', patience=10)
model_checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint('weightsResNet50test.hdf5', monitor='val_loss', save_best_only=True)

# Training the model using the ImageDataGenerators and saving the training history
history = model.fit(train_generator, validation_data=validation_generator, epochs=1000)

# Plotting the training and validation accuracy over epochs
fig1 = plt.gcf()
plt.plot(history.history['accuracy'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_accuracy'])
plt.axis(ymin=0.4, ymax=1)
plt.grid()
plt.title('Model Accuracy')
plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
plt.xlabel('Epochs')
plt.legend(['train', 'validation'])
plt.show()

predictions = model.predict(test_generator)
test_labels = test_generator.classes
class_labels = np.argmax(predictions, axis=1)
report = classification_report(test_labels, class_labels, zero_division=1)
print(report)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the poor metrics in the classification report for the training data is `shuffle=True` in your `train_generator`. If you change that to `False`, you should see your 99% accuracy.

As for the test data, I can't say much other than it's likely just overfitting. Your dataset also seems quite imbalanced.

Comment: Well I've changed shuffle to True in test_generator, but haven't tried it yet. Do you think that it should also solve the test problem? Or at least make the metrics better? How does is affect scores that much?

Comment: `train_generator.classes` gives you a sorted list of classes (based on the directory structure). This list remains the same whether or not you shuffle the dataset. So when you do shuffle the dataset, the labels given by `train_generator.classes` no longer match the images.